# Can anyone help how to use event from Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.Enable)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to Kendo. I am using `Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.Enable)` in MVC cshtml, and I'm unable to add a change event for this checkbox. The `Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor` has `.Events(e => e.Change("PopulateCountry"))`, but I dont see same type of event in `CheckBox`.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor` helper renders a regular html5 checkbox. It is not actually a kendo widget like `Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor` creates. I believe this is why the helper for `CheckBox` is lacking an `.Events` option.

Regardless, you can use the `.HtmlAttributes` option to add a change handler to the checkbox element instead:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { onchange = "PopulateCountry();" })
```